# Not able to run message queue

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have created a spring boot project where it is listening to a message sent by a producer. When i am sending a message i am not able to run the receiver and getting below exception

Exception:

```
Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'artemisQueue' - retrying 
using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=1, 
maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Failed to create session factory; nested 
exception is ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED 
message=AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available 
servers.]
```

Comment: It is seen that your app cannot be connected to message queue. Did you define your connection info in application.properties

Comment: There's really not enough information here to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Hi Justin I am trying to run a springboot application with embedded broker. When i am trying run the application i am getting this error. I have tried to change the application.properties but no luck and i am not sure what should i paste here so that You can help me. Apologies for the same. Could you please navigate me to right resource for the embedded mq(github example). And as per my understanding there is no need to run artemis broker explicitly when i am running with Embedded mq.

Comment: Maybe you have create the broker but not the address/queue or perhaps artemis service is stopped? Do you reach http://localhost:8161 and can you see your queue?